# website authorization behaving very unusually

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, authorization

I am using `forms` authentication in asp.net4. But the authorization is behaving very unusually.
Following is my web.config snippet-

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" timeout="2880" protection="All" path="/" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
  <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

When i try to open any web page i am redirected to `Login` page as expected. If close my browser i should be logged out, but thats not happening although i am setting `persistentCookie=false` as follow
`FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username, false);`
Now after closing browser if a login again i am considered authenticated user, but if i clear `cookie cache` in my browser than i wont be considered authenticated user.

I am not setting cookie anywhere and i dont want persistent cookie, than why is this happening.
Please tell me if i am missing something.

**Anobody know something related to this**
I just found that this problem is only with Chrome 21.0, and not with Firefox 7.0 or Opera 11.4 (problem of authenticating even though session ends).

Comment: Post more of your code.  Do you know what the property `timeout` is doing, seems like you don't, since your asking this question.

Comment: @Ramhound No i dint what is timeout doing, i am new to all this, and i have a lot of thing ahead of me to learn. so i dont think down voting is necessary. it would be much appreciated if you give answer

Answer (score 1):

When you use `authentication mode="Forms"` your auth credentials stored in cookies by default. If you want to change this behaviour you can use `cookieless="UseUri"` attribute, than your credential will be stored in the URL. You can find more inforamtion [forms Element for authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/1d3t3c61.aspx).

**timeout** attribute specify how long cookies will be stored (in minutes) by default it is 30.

Comment: i have removed all attrbutes except loginUrl,still the problem persists. and i cant use Uri cookies for other reasons, anything you can suggest.